# Xor logical condition in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a logical XOR expression available in pyspark?
The documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=streaming) says to use `^` but I am getting the following error when I try doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boolean operations on `pyspark.sql.column.Column` objects allowing you to use `&`, `|`, and `~` are defined [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5dd581c88ab111377175b673994153072fe9ec77/python/pyspark/sql/column.py#L239). As you can see unfortunately XOR operation is not among defined ones.

Thus:

```
df = spark.range(1000)
df.where((df.id >= 20) & (df.id <= 40)) # will be ok
df.where((df.id >= 20) ^ (df.id <= 40)) # will result in error
```

You can however write something like this:

```
df.where((df.id >= 10).cast('int')\
        .bitwiseXOR((df.id <= 90).cast('int')).cast('boolean')).show()
```

In case you are extremely unhappy with the lack of `(df.id >= 20) ^ (df.id <= 40)` you can use something like the following at your own risk (I don't recommend doing it):

```
import pyspark
df = spark.range(50)
pyspark.sql.column.Column.__xor__ = lambda x, y: x.cast('int').bitwiseXOR(y.cast('int')).cast('boolean')
df.where((df.id >= 10) ^ (df.id <= 40)).show()
```

Comment: Err, did you have a look at line 273 of that link you provided?

Comment: Yes, I did.  I think you mean line 287 and it it defines `bitwiseXOR`. Line 273 contains doc string definition.

Comment: It was the docstring I was referring to since it's better than trying to decipher the code :-)

Comment: Well, it is an integer operation, not a boolean one. Plus it is not something one can use with an operator notation, I understood the question was about that :).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I realize that I cant use bitwise and logical operators interchangeably. I have resorted to using the `~` like so: ```df.where(((df.id >= 20) | (df.id <= 40)) & ~(df.where((df.id >= 20) & (df.id <= 40))))```

Comment: I think you meant `df.where(((df.id >= 20) | (df.id <= 40)) & ~ ((df.id >= 20) & (df.id <= 40)))` -  you have extra `df.where`.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in that link states that you should *use* `^`, the closet occurrence seems to be:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import Row
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(a=170, b=75)])
>>> df.select(df.a.bitwiseXOR(df.b)).collect()
[Row((a ^ b)=225)]
```

Other occurrences of `^` are used for both regular expressions and exponents so are unrelated.

That particular case is showing a *result* with the `^` character in it, but it's very much telling you to *use* `bitwiseXOR()`. However, there's a big difference between bitwise and logical or operations (unless enacted only on bit values of zero and one in an environment that conflates the two, of course).

And, given that the only occurrences of "logical" on that page have nothing to do with logical *operators,* the operation appear to not be available.

Comment: Might be important to add that `bitwiseXOR` won't work directly on logical type - you'll need to cast both operands to integer and then cast result back to `boolean`.