# xor logical condition on the value of pyspark.sql.column in python pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I need to filter DF in pySpark to check if a cell’s value equals to the results of this cell’s XOR a number for example:
df.num ^ xor_num == df.num
Here is my code:

```
new_df = old_df.filter(old_df.num ^ xor_num == old.df.num)
```

But I get the error:
unsupported operand type for ^:’column’ and ‘int’

(The reason is obvious, those are different types)
So my question is - how can I use this filter method to make a bit operator on the data to compare it to itself?

There is a similar question in stack overflow:

[Xor logical condition in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62442028/xor-logical-condition-in-pyspark)

BUT it is not relevant and Does not solve my problem, because it is how to make a xor on the results and not on the cell input.
Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your `xor_num` is a integer, you can transfer the integer to column by `lit`:

```
new_df = old_df.filter(func.col('num').bitwiseXOR(func.lit(xor_num))==func.col('num'))
```